# DNN 9 SPA Module QuickSettings

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I am very sorry to have to do a post like this, but I have been looking everywhere and I have not found a good example of how to use/reference quick settings on a SPA module for DNN 9.  IS there anyway that someone could point me to some sample code or give an example of how you can save/reference a modules quick settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [Restaurant Menu](https://github.com/DotNetNuclear/DnnRestaurantMenu) example module has a [SPA version](https://github.com/DotNetNuclear/DnnRestaurantMenu/tree/master/RestaurantMenu.SPA) that with a full, working implementation of the Quick Settings.

**Edit:**
In my above example, I just access the setting in the controller webAPI method for the view.  If you would like to spit out the setting as a SPA token in your view html, you use [ModuleContext:{SettingName}].

In my above example, I am setting the module setting in with the following code:

```
ModuleController.Instance.UpdateModuleSetting(ActiveModule.ModuleID, "RestaurantMenu_CurrencyCulture", settings.CurrencyCulture);
```

The second parameter is the setting's dictionary key name.  Therefore, to get this setting value in the View.html, I would use the following SPA token: `

```
[ModuleContext:RestaurantMenu_CurrencyCulture]
```

Comment: Thank you, how do you access the settings in the html files? this link: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/docs/developers/about-modules/spa-module-development.html seems to suggest that you can access it like you would a module context property

Comment: Added more detail to my answer. Hope this helps.